# The invalid choice in the code appears in the output screen

Tags: c

Why does the "Invalid" appear in my output under everything? The invalid choice is the last thing in the menu, am I'm using the statement right or what exactly is wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void two_assesments();
void three_assesments();
void four_assesments();
void five_assesments();
void six_assesments();

int main( void )
{
    int c;

    printf("\n*****Student Grade Calculator*****\n\n");
    printf(" Developed By...\n");
    printf(" Carlos\n");
    printf(" University of South Wales\n");
    printf(" =================================================================\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("\n Please enter the number of assessments in the module : \n");
    scanf("%d",&c);

    if (c==2) {
        two_assesments();
    }
    if (c==3) {
        three_assesments();
    }
    if (c==4) {
        four_assesments();
    }
    if (c==5) {
        five_assesments();
    }
    if (c==6) {
        six_assesments();
    }
    else
        if (c=!7); {
            { printf("\nInvalid"); }
        }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: its basically this :-

Comment: else
                if (c=!7); {
                    { printf("\nInvalid"); }

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
else
    if (c=!7); { . . .
```

You have a `;` after `if ()`

I would suggest you use a `switch` statement like this

```
switch (c) {
  case 2:   two_assesments(); break;
  case 3: three_assesments(); break;
  case 4:  four_assesments(); break;
  case 5:  five_assesments(); break;
  case 6:   six_assesments(); break;
  default: printf("\nInvalid\n");
}
```

to make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem, consider what happens if the user enters `2`. The first `if` statement evaluates true and the `two_assesments` function is called. The next three `if` statements fail. Then we get to the `if (c==6)`. That also fails, so the `else` is evaluated.  And here you have two problems.

First is the semi-colon. Because you have a semicolon after the `if (c=!7)` the compiler sees your code as

```
    if (c==6) {
        six_assesments();
    }
    else {
        if (c=!7)
            ; /* do nothing */
    }
    printf("\nInvalid");
```

In other words, because of the semicolon, the final `if` statement has no effect, and the `printf` isn't even part of the `else`. So "Invalid" always gets printed.

The other problem is the `=!`. What you meant to say was `if (c!=7)`. By reversing the `=` and the `!`, you actually assign `0` to `c`, and the `if` always evaluates to false. The compiler should be giving you a warning about that.

A slightly improved version of the code would look like this

```
    if (c==2)
        two_assesments();
    else if (c==3)
        three_assesments();
    else if (c==4)
        four_assesments();
    else if (c==5)
        five_assesments();
    else if (c==6)
        six_assesments();
    else
        printf("\nInvalid");
```